# Screen zoomed after removing external monitor

Tags: 12.04, hp, external-monitor

Hi I am having an issue after disconnecting from an external monitor that my display is enlarged the windows run off the screen so I can open catalyst control or
**settings->display** to try and see what the problem is.  I'm thinking its from unplugging from my monitor but Ubuntu is usually smart enough to figure that out.  Any one whose had a similar problem or anyone with suggestions I'd greatly appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

I have no solution but I can confirm this.

I've experienced the same problem a couple of times. I plug in the TV from time to time and sometimes I am stuck with a 3000+resolution after!

I disable the TV. It goes away after restart, but it is really annoying.